# AWX Cannot find KDC for REALM

Tags: kerberos, ansible, ansible-tower

### Cannot find KDC for REALM

I have an issue with Kerberos and AWX. If I create a ticket manually with
`kinit testeruser@TEST.PUBLIC.COM`, it works without any problem.

But if I will use AWX (Credential was set via UI), I get the following error messeage.

> TASK [Add or update registry path Birthday Attack]
> ***************************** fatal: [test.public.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed":
> false, "msg": "Kerberos auth failure for principal
> testuser@TEST.PUBLIC.COM with pexpect: Cannot find KDC for realm
> "TEST.PUBLIC.COM" while getting initial credentials",
> "unreachable": true}

Have someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
- add privileged: true to your Task container or the main.yml file and re-deploy.

vi awx/installer/local_docker/tasks/main.yml

- name: AWX Task Container
  docker_container:
  name: awx_task
  state: started

  > privileged: true
- login to your container and install the following: yum install krb5-workstation, krb5-devel, krb5-libs, gcc, python-devel, pip install kerberos